# ImportError: cannot import name 'persist'

Tags: deep-learning, cntk

I want to persist a trained model in CNTK and found the 'persist' functionality after some amount of searching. However, there seems to be some error in importing it.

```
from cntk import persist
```

This is throwing ImportError.

Am I doing something the wrong way? Or is this no longer supported? Is there an alternate way to persist a model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

persist is from an earlier beta.  save_model is now a method of every CNTK function. So instead of doing save_model(z, filename) you do z.save_model(filename). Load_model works the same as before but you import it from cntk.ops.functions.  For an example, see: https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/blob/v2.0.beta7.0/Tutorials/CNTK_203_Reinforcement_Learning_Basics.ipynb or https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/blob/v2.0.beta7.0/bindings/python/cntk/tests/persist_test.py

Comment: Even newer: This function is now just called `.save(filename)`

Answer (score 1):

The functionality has moved to cntk functions. The new way is `mynetwork.save_model(...)` where `mynetwork` represents the root of your computation (typically the prediction). For loading the model you can just say `mynetwork = C.load_model(...)`